# Bootstrap - Show popover on document ready

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

on my application, when a user is logged in and browsing their name and avatar is displayed in the top right of the navbar. Example:

```
<li>
   <a class="btn" href="#">
       <img id="user-avatar" src="{{ $userAvatar }}" alt="" /> {{ $userNickname }}
   </a>
</li>
```

However I would like a popover to show for 5 seconds, below the username/avatar area that says "You have successfully logged in".  This is possible, as I have a session which is set for only the page after a successful login (after the page is changed/refreshed it is destroyed).

My plan was to have the popover attributes set on the list item already, and when the login session is set it run a bit of javascript to trigger the popover:

```
<li id="popover" rel="popover" data-content="You Logged In" data-original-title="Success!">
   <a class="btn" href="#">
      <img id="user-avatar" src="{{ $userAvatar }}" alt="" /> {{ $userNickname }}
   </a>
</li>
@if (Session::has('login_success'))
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#popover').popover();
       });
    </script>
@endif
```

I know I'm missing the data-animation="bottom", but whatever I do just nothing happens!

Comment: what if you try `$('#popover').popover().click();` the popover should be activated on click or you could: `.popover('show')`

Comment: have you added the proper javascript files? ie. `bootstrap-tooltip.js` and `bootstrap-popover.js`. because the latter depends on the former.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code:   `$('#popover').popover();` just instantiates the popover for the element, it doesn't show it.

You want to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#popover").popover('show');
   });
</script>
```

If that fails to work in a browser try running it after the window has fully loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
       $("#popover").popover('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, the window.load worked! Also with the 'show' as well. Cheers, just need to get it looking good now :>